# PowerBi Embedded Is there a way to just present a Visual from the sheet site?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I can't find any way to just present a object(like a Table or a matris) from the powerbi sheet in an embedded link? anyone have any ide?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a whole report or just a visual (also called tile), more information is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embed-visual

Please have a look if you haven't already [Power BI Embedded Analytic Playground](https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/), with lots of examples and resources for embedding content

Comment: Thanks @Jon I have watched some videos about the new playground. But there is no way to just get a url and see the title(objekt/specefik table)? I will do some embedded to a system called stratsys but i havent got my access yet so i dont know how the integrations is. I can see that i have objekt integration from powerbi but not how,

Comment: do ju also know how i can point to a special sheets from powerbi with URL like

Comment: ...Auth=true&pageName=sheetName

Comment: There is no way to just show a visual with an url with some filter or stuff like that. I need a code/script from like playground to use it?

Comment: Not in a url, you'll need to address the object in a bit of java script to render to the page

Comment: Thanks, then its the code from playground you mean?